# HttpClient not sending authorization Bearer token in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that calls an ASP.NET Core WebApi using HttpClient, but I have to send the authorization header, the problem is that my HttpClient won't send the authorization header.

I have a service for calling the webapi that has the following constructor:

```cs
        public ApiService(HttpClient httpClient, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            string token = accessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("JWToken"); // gets user token
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.BaseUrlApi); //sets the base URL of the webapi
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            _httpClient = httpClient; // assigns to a private property "private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;"
        }
```

Then, when I post data to the webapi, I use the following method:

```cs
        public async Task<User> PostAsync(string url, User user)
        {
            StringContent jsonContent = new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, _jsonSettings), // _jsonSettings is a JsonSerializerSettings object
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

            using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse =
                await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, jsonContent);
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(responseString, _jsonSettings);
        }
```

For requests that do not require an Authorization header, it works pretty fine, but it doesn't send the Authorization header, I have tried instantiating a new HttClient, using HttpRequestMessage and then SendAsync, but it never works, I also tried using `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");` but it doesn't work, also `TryAddWithoutValidation`, but doesn't work.
The worst is, when I check my httpClient object, the authorization token is there:

[image]

But then I get a 401 message from my webapi, and when I check the request received in the webapi, the authorization header is empty, and my webapi works fine when it receives requests from ajax calls, or applications like insomnia and postman.

I can't figure out what I am missing.

EDIT:

In my webapi, the request that's arriving is:
[image]

My authorization header is {}

Now, when I receive a request from insomnia, for example, I have the following headers:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a logging handler as in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers so you can observe the raw request properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you are using looks as though it should work, I tried something similar on my end and it added the JWT as expected. Is it possible that the 401 is legitimately referring to a bad token? I'd try decoding it with: https://jwt.io/ and validate that all the claims in it make sense (e.g. expiration) and that it is signed correctly.

### UPDATE

Adding some code that's very similar to what you are trying to do that does work for me, FYI this is making a phone call via an API, leaving the JWT generation and command generation out for simplicity

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command,
    Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt);

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.nexmo.com/v1/calls", content).Result;
```

I can confirm that this most certainly adds the JWT as a bearer token into the header (it would not work otherwise)

hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I check the jwt token and it is valid, the expiration is fine and once I provided the secret token it said Signature Verified. I added the pictures of the requests received from my httpclient (asp.net core) and from insomnia.

Comment: @AlefDuarte I added an update which has the exact code I used (which is very similar to yours - that is definitely adding the JWT as a bearer token

Comment: I still get the same problem, but since your code should work, now I know it must be some configuration I'm overlooking and not how httpclient is being instantiated. Thank you for your help, If I have any update I'll let you know.

Comment: Where is your post data. I want send a post request with bearer token and json at request body. Do not get any proper solution.